# How to link to a component using persistant header that's outside of BrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm attempting to link to somewhere within my application using react-router-dom within an appBar/header that is persistent throughout the app. I keep getting "TypeError: history is undefined" when I attempt to use RRD within the header component.

[image]

I've been playing around with this for a good few hours now and I'm not getting any where with it. I can't think straight thanks to the heat, and I'm clearly searching for the wrong answers in my searches. The best solution I have come-up with thus-far is having each component contain the header component at the top but this is obv not ideal. I know I must be missing something simple as this can't be an uncommon pattern.

### Demo Code

#### Node Stuff

```sh
npx create-react-app rdr-header --template typescript
npm install react-router-dom
```

#### App.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useHistory,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = (to: string) => {
    history.push(to);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick("/ger")}>German</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick("/")}>English</button>
      </header>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={English} />
          <Route path='/ger' component={German} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

const English = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push("/ger");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>English</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to German</button>
    </>
  );
};

const German = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push("/");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>German</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to English</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create separate component for header

`header.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function Header() {
  let history = useHistory();
  const handleClick = to => {
    history.push(to);
  };

  return (
    <header className="App-header">
      <button onClick={() => handleClick('/ger')}>German</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick('/')}>English</button>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Use `Header` component inside `Router` like below:-

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useHistory
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './header.js';   // import header component 

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />     // use Header component inside Router
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={English} />
          <Route path="/ger" component={German} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

const English = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push('/ger');
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>English</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to German</button>
    </>
  );
};

const German = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push('/');
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>German</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to English</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Moving the header into he router didn't work but once it was a imported component is did. Which doesn't really make any sense to me but thanks?

Comment: @JayCork the component where you make the `useHistory` call has to be inside the `Router`.  So just rearranging the JSX won't help if the `useHistory` and the `Router` are both in the same `App` component.  That's why you need to make `Header` a separate component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the history object using `history.push()`, you can use the `<Link>` or `<NavLink>` components from react-router.

[React Router - Link component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

Make sure to place the header component inside the Router component.